# Выводится много цифр после запятой

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, sqlite3

у меня есть команда

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['energydrink', 'энергетик'], chat_type=[types.ChatType.SUPERGROUP, types.ChatType.GROUP])
async def drinkenergy(message: types.Message):
    number = random.uniform(1, 5)
    number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))
    db.add_energetik(number, message.from_user.id)
    total_liters = db.get_totalenergetik(message.from_user.id) # здесь был лишний аргумент
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'@{message.from_user.username}, ты выпил(а) {number} л. энергетика.\nВыпито всего: {total_liters[0]} л.', reply_markup=deletemarkup)
```

И в db.py есть:

```
def get_totalenergetik(self, user_id):
            with self.connection:
                return self.cursor.execute("SELECT `number` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?;", (user_id, )).fetchall() ### UPD
```

И бывает случаются такие приколы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно решить?

Ещё из-за этого в базе данных такой прикол иногда тоже бывает:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Округлить число?

Comment: Десятичные числа не представляются точно в памяти компьютера. Всегда будет куча девяток в конце. `number = float('{:.1f}'.format(number))` - не имеет смысла. Форматировать надо в момент печати числа.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy некоторые представляются точно, например `65.5`

Comment: а что за функция add_energetik? можно посмотреть?

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, ну чтобы было число к примеру 6, и после запятой одна цифра, а не много 9999999

Answer (score 1):

Используйте округление до приемлемого количества знаков после запятой при форматировании. Например,

```
total_liters = [70.6999999999999999]
print(f'Выпито всего: {total_liters[0]:.1f} л.')  # .1 - один знак после запятой
```

выведет `Выпито всего: 70.7 л.`